# How can this equals() method return true?

Tags: java, equals

i was reading equals contract in *Effective Java* and in the transitive part i got into a doubt , in the below code :

```
public class Point {
    private final int x;
    private final int y;
    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
```

Now we Have this

```
@Override 
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (!(o instanceof Point))
        return false;
    Point p = (Point)o;
    return p.x == x && p.y == y;
}


public class ColorPoint extends Point {
    private final Color color;
    public ColorPoint(int x, int y, Color color) {
        super(x, y);
        this.color = color;
    }
    // Remainder omitted
}
// Broken - violates symmetry!
@Override 
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (!(o instanceof ColorPoint))
        return false;
    return super.equals(o) && ((ColorPoint) o).color == color;
}
```

`ColorPoint cp = new ColorPoint(1, 2, Color.RED);`

`Point p = new Point(1, 2);`

and if i run p.equals(cp) ,  it should return false because
`return super.equals(o) && ((ColorPoint) o).color == color;` is not valid for both classes because `point` class dosen't contain the variable `Color`

Why in the book it is written true ?

Comment: It would really help if you could indent your code properly, and provide the whole thing in a [mcve] so we could copy/paste/compile/run, instead of having to take snippets and put them into a main method ourselves.

Comment: Note that you *can't* run `p.equals(cp)` as neither `p` nor `cp` are variables you've declared.

Comment: With `p.equals(cp)`, you are calling `Point.equals`. The contents of `ColorPoint.equals` are not consulted. It is different if you call `cp.equals(p)`. You have written a non-symmetrical equality relationship.

Comment: got the ans ... bad from my side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see clearly in your code:

```
ColorPoint cp = new ColorPoint(1, 2, Color.RED);
Point p = new Point(1, 2);  // create a Point
p.equals(cp)                // call Point::equals
```

You call `Point::equals()` method... which don't compare color, think about *`Point` **does not have color** attribute*.

But anyway, you can compare both elements with `ColorPoint::equals` using `cp.equals(p)`:

```
ColorPoint cp = new ColorPoint(1, 2, Color.RED);
Point p = new Point(1, 2);          // create a Point
System.out.println(p.equals(cp));   // call Point::equals
System.out.println(cp.equals(p));   // call ColorPoint::equals
```

Will output:

```
true
false
```

**NOTE:** be careful!!! 
This `false` is not for the different `color` attribute, is because `p` **is not** `instanceof ColorPoint`!!.

---

**EDIT:**

> thanks a lot , thats bad from my side ..i should have figured it `:(`

Well, when you are experienced in this cases is easier to figure out, but in the begining can be hard to understand. In this cases, to follow the flow of the app I debug, but you achieve easier and faster this info adding print statements.

For example:

**`ColorPoint::equals`**

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    System.out.println("equals ColorPoint");
    if (!(o instanceof ColorPoint))
        return false;
    return super.equals(o) && ((ColorPoint) o).color == color;
}
```

**`Point::equals`**

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    System.out.println("equals Point");
    if (!(o instanceof Point))
        return false;
    Point p = (Point) o;
    return p.x == x && p.y == y;
}
```

Same test program will output:

```
equals Point
true
equals ColorPoint
false
```

Which gives you clues about what is going on!.

Comment: thanks a lot , thats bad from my side ..i should have figured it :(

Comment: for understanding this stuff... IMHO introducing print statements help, let me make an edit.

Comment: @Amol check it now  ;)